# Girar un semi-circulo SVG en css

Tags: html, css, web, svg, diseño

estoy tratando de hacer girar esos dos semi-circulos alrededor del circulo central y parce que el centro de dichos semi-circulos (#circle1 / #circle2) no esta centrado y al girar se sale de su recorrido deseado. ya probe cambiando el origen y el box

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aqui esta el svg

```
<svg width="58" height="64" viewBox="0 0 58 64" fill="none" >
                    <g id="web-logo-design">
                    <g id="logo" clip-path="url(#clip0)">
                    <path id="Vector" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M32.0356 10.6667C43.7938 10.6862 53.3333 20.2364 53.3333 32C53.3333 43.7742 43.776 53.3333 32 53.3333C20.2258 53.3333 10.6667 43.7742 10.6667 32C10.6667 20.2364 20.208 10.6862 31.9662 10.6667H32.0356ZM38.6027 39.1111H25.3991C26.5351 46.6951 29.3849 51.5556 32 51.5556C34.6169 51.5556 37.4667 46.6951 38.6027 39.1111V39.1111ZM50.2204 39.1111H40.4018C39.6444 44.4178 38.0533 48.7147 35.984 51.1484C42.5067 49.7973 47.8436 45.1929 50.2204 39.1111ZM23.6 39.1111H13.7796C16.1582 45.1929 21.4951 49.7973 28.0178 51.1484C25.9484 48.7147 24.3573 44.4178 23.6 39.1111ZM23.3813 26.6667H13.184C12.5956 28.7396 11.8667 32.6916 13.184 37.3333H23.3813C23.0471 34.1084 22.9991 30.3556 23.3813 26.6667ZM38.832 26.6667H25.1698C24.8231 29.8667 24.7698 33.648 25.1698 37.3333H38.832C39.1804 34.1138 39.2302 30.3467 38.832 26.6667ZM50.8178 26.6667H40.6204C40.7307 27.7191 41.168 32.0338 40.6204 37.3333H50.8178C52.1351 32.6898 51.4062 28.7378 50.8178 26.6667ZM28.0178 12.8516C21.4951 14.2027 16.1582 18.8071 13.7796 24.8889H23.6C24.3573 19.5822 25.9484 15.2836 28.0178 12.8516ZM38.6027 24.8889C37.4667 17.3049 34.6169 12.4444 32 12.4444C29.3849 12.4444 26.5351 17.3049 25.3991 24.8889H38.6027ZM35.984 12.8516C38.0533 15.2836 39.6444 19.5822 40.4018 24.8889H50.2204C47.8436 18.8071 42.5067 14.2027 35.984 12.8516" fill="white"/>
                    </g>
                    <path id="circle2" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M32 0C14.3269 0 0 14.3269 0 32C0 49.6731 14.3269 64 32 64V58C17.6406 58 6 46.3594 6 32C6 17.6406 17.6406 6 32 6V0Z" fill="#1D6460"/>
                    <path id="circle1" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M32 57.5975C32.1183 57.5992 32.2368 57.6 32.3556 57.6C46.2977 57.6 57.6 46.2977 57.6 32.3556C57.6 18.4134 46.2977 7.11111 32.3556 7.11111C32.2368 7.11111 32.1183 7.11193 32 7.11357V10.1139C32.1183 10.112 32.2368 10.1111 32.3556 10.1111C44.6408 10.1111 54.6 20.0703 54.6 32.3556C54.6 44.6408 44.6408 54.6 32.3556 54.6C32.2368 54.6 32.1183 54.5991 32 54.5972V57.5975Z" fill="white"/>
                    </g>
                    <defs>
                    <clipPath id="clip0">
                    <rect width="42.6667" height="42.6667" fill="white" transform="translate(10.6667 10.6667)"/>
                    </clipPath>
                    </defs>
                    </svg>
```

Hay una manera de hacerlo en css? O una forma de hacerlo yo mismo en figma / adobe xd y luego exportarlo? Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @adro, [¿esto responde a tu pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329419/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-un-cargador-similar-html-y-css/331211#331211)

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Sii, encontre donde estaba fallando mi svg gracias a eso. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Aunque creo que tienes ya una solución, esta es mi respuesta. He simplificado tu código y en lugar de utilizar dos trazados con relleno estoy utilizando dos circulos con un stroke más ancho. También estoy utilizando el atributo stroke-dasharray donde el valor para el stroke es igual al valor para el espacios y a su turno iguales a la mitad de la longitud del trazado. Para animar los circulos estoy animando el valor del atributo stroke-dashoffset (el desplazamiento).

```css
svg{background:black}

#circle1 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: dash1 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash1 {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 73.821;
  }
}

#circle2 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: dash2 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash2 {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 91.1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="358" viewBox="0 0 64 64" fill="none">
  <g id="web-logo-design">
    <g id="logo">
      <path id="Vector" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M32.0356 10.6667C43.7938 10.6862 53.3333 20.2364 53.3333 32C53.3333 43.7742 43.776 53.3333 32 53.3333C20.2258 53.3333 10.6667 43.7742 10.6667 32C10.6667 20.2364 20.208 10.6862 31.9662 10.6667H32.0356ZM38.6027 39.1111H25.3991C26.5351 46.6951 29.3849 51.5556 32 51.5556C34.6169 51.5556 37.4667 46.6951 38.6027 39.1111V39.1111ZM50.2204 39.1111H40.4018C39.6444 44.4178 38.0533 48.7147 35.984 51.1484C42.5067 49.7973 47.8436 45.1929 50.2204 39.1111ZM23.6 39.1111H13.7796C16.1582 45.1929 21.4951 49.7973 28.0178 51.1484C25.9484 48.7147 24.3573 44.4178 23.6 39.1111ZM23.3813 26.6667H13.184C12.5956 28.7396 11.8667 32.6916 13.184 37.3333H23.3813C23.0471 34.1084 22.9991 30.3556 23.3813 26.6667ZM38.832 26.6667H25.1698C24.8231 29.8667 24.7698 33.648 25.1698 37.3333H38.832C39.1804 34.1138 39.2302 30.3467 38.832 26.6667ZM50.8178 26.6667H40.6204C40.7307 27.7191 41.168 32.0338 40.6204 37.3333H50.8178C52.1351 32.6898 51.4062 28.7378 50.8178 26.6667ZM28.0178 12.8516C21.4951 14.2027 16.1582 18.8071 13.7796 24.8889H23.6C24.3573 19.5822 25.9484 15.2836 28.0178 12.8516ZM38.6027 24.8889C37.4667 17.3049 34.6169 12.4444 32 12.4444C29.3849 12.4444 26.5351 17.3049 25.3991 24.8889H38.6027ZM35.984 12.8516C38.0533 15.2836 39.6444 19.5822 40.4018 24.8889H50.2204C47.8436 18.8071 42.5067 14.2027 35.984 12.8516" fill="red" />
    </g>
  </g>

  
  <path id="circle1" stroke="white" fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="73.821" d="M32,8.5A23,23 0 0 1 32,55.5A23,23 0 0 1 32,8.5z"/>
  
  <path id="circle2" stroke="#1D6460" fill="none" stroke-width="5.5" stroke-dasharray="91.1" d="M32,3A29,29 0 0 0 32,61 A29,29 0 0 0 32,3z"/>
</svg>
```