# Aplicar css a un div que tiene pseudoclase

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo este código:

```css
.vjs-loading-spinner {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
  opacity: .85;
  text-align: left;
  border: 6px solid rgba(43, 51, 63, .7);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  visibility: visible;
}

.vjs-loading-spinner::after,
.vjs-loading-spinner::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: -6px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
  border: inherit;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="vjs-loading-spinner"></div>
```

Lo quiero hacer es darle efecto con **JavaScript** al **spinner** que se forma, lo que se me ocurre es aplicar un css a estas clases: `.vjs-loading-spinner::after` y `.vjs-loading-spinner::before` ya que estas forman el medio circulo que pretendo ir moviendo para dar el efecto deseado, lo que tengo es esto:

```
$(".vjs-loading-spinner::after, .vjs-loading-spinner::before").css("transform": "rotate(90deg)");
```

El problema es que no hace nada, no se si porque a las clases que tienen una pseudoclase no se le puede aplicar `css` con `jquery` o `javascript`, o no se que este haciendo mal.

Comment: Tenes un error de sintaxis, es `"transform", "rotate...` (_params separados por coma_). Si la idea es rotar ambos pseudo elementos ¿rotar el elemento no seria lo mas simple? eg: `$(".vjs-loading-spinner").css("transform", "rotate(90deg)");`

Comment: Hola @Jorge, [responde esto a tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329419/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-un-cargador-similar-html-y-css/331211#331211)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes agregar un @keyframes y aplicarle a los :before, :after y esta es una forma de como hacerlo:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$(".vjs-loading-spinner").css('display','block');

});
```

```css
.vjs-loading-spinner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
  opacity: .85;
  text-align: left;
  border: 6px solid rgba(43, 51, 63, .7);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  visibility: visible;
}

.vjs-loading-spinner::after,
.vjs-loading-spinner::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: -6px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
  border: inherit;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: #fff;
}

.vjs-loading-spinner::after,
.vjs-loading-spinner::before {
   animation: animate 0.5s linear infinite;
 }

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vjs-loading-spinner"></div>
```

Espero esto solucione tu duda.